# Paypal Webhooks

Tags: paypal, webhooks, paypal-ipn, paypal-webhooks

I have setup webhook and IPNs (Instanst Payment Notifications) with in paypal.  It is my understanding that if I select ' * All Events ' within the webhook setup, that I would receive a webhook for any transaction that occurred in paypal - including ebay sales that were paid through paypal.

Since setting up the webhook, I have had a few sales go through paypal, but 0 webhook notifications were receivied.

Am I missing something about paypal webhooks?

Comment: Met the same situation with you, zero webhook events fire related to my transaction

Answer (score -1):

The most effective way before you start receiving payments is usually by testing your webhook events and if they're going through, follow the below step

1. Set up your development environment.
2. Configure a webhook listener.
3. Validate your listener configuration with mock webhook events.
4. Subscribe to events.
5. Verify event notifications.

Go to this link for step 3
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#validate-your-listener-configuration-with-mock-webhook-events